# logstash scheduler in yaml file

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-jdbc

In the previous version of my logstash yaml file I used `schedule => "* * * * *"`

Now I'm trying to schedule it to tqice a day ( lets say 6 am and pm ), but it doesn`t work anymore.
File content:

```
input {
  jdbc{
      clean_run => true
        jdbc_driver_library => "../config/postgresql-42.2.23.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
        trigger => {
            schedule => 
                daily => 
                    at => [ "18:00","06:00"]
            }

        statement => 'SELECT tenant_id as id , full_name , email , phone FROM public."Tenants" '
        use_column_value => true
        tracking_column => "id"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
...
  }
}
```

Comment: From where did you get this `trigger` option? This does not exist, you need to use [schedule](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#plugins-inputs-jdbc-schedule) option. To run it twice you will need two `jdbc` input, one configured to run `06:00` and other configured to run `18:00`.

Comment: Are you sure you cannot use "0 0 6,18 * *"?

Comment: @Badger didn`t try yet. , will try it.

Comment: @leandrojmp from the ES docs, but i tried without the `trigger` , are you sure about the 2 jdbc?  i say many kinds of scheduler options...

Answer (score 1):

So I found the problem, there are no `trigger`, `daily` and `at` properties.

It should simply be: `schedule => "0 0 6,18 * * *"`